# How to properly wait for an object to be instantiated

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I launch the camera activity and tell it to set the image to a specific file.  When the activity returns, I am grabbing that file and trying to upload it to a server but sometimes the camera activity hasn't finished writing to the file so I get a NullPointerException.

What is the best practice for making sure you don't have this race condition.  I tried synchrnized() but that didn't seem to fix the problem.

```
synchronized(picFile) {
    imageUploader.uploadImage(picFile); }
```

I remember my professor in college telling me he would hunt me down if we did an idle wait loop so I feel like there should be a better way of doing this than some loop that just waits.

Thanks

Comment: Could we get some more context, here?

Comment: While I have no exact idea what "file is null" means, there's ``android.os.FileObserver`` that might suit for waiting until captured image has been stored properly.

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit.  Hopefully that helps.  And thanks harism I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a ContentObserver to notify you of changes in media store and verify if the file exists in the OnChange callback.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver)